# Good way to select reference and/or performing normalization of data points across experiments?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, experiment-design, normalization, research-design

I have a set of objects `S1 = {a1, b1, c1, d1, ..., z1}` that perturbed a reference object `q` and were tested for effects in Experiment 1. The measurements for `S1` were normalized to `q`.

From this dataset, I derived modifications `S2 = {a2, b2, c2, d2, .., z2}` for further testing using machine learning, and included as references `R = {q, a1, b1, z1}` from the original set due to limited experimental capacity, i.e. `R != S1`.

What is the correct way to normalize `S2` such that `S2` and `S1` measurements are comparable?

I am guessing normalizing `S2` w.r.t `q` alone won't suffice and that learning a regression curve between `{q, a1, b1, z1}` values from `S1` and `S2` might allow me to learn the shift if there is any, due to batch effects and such.

Is this sufficient? Or an overkill, since normalizing `S2` to `q` alone would be sufficient? Is there a definitive or standard way to plan the normalization so that it is robust across experimental rounds?

A naive solution would be to test at each round the union of all objects from earlier rounds and then normalizing everything w.r.t. `q` in current round to propose further modifications in the next round. But, of course, this is expensive.